# firebase auth is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I got this TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__firebase**.c.auth is not a function

The line i got an error is the first line.

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(authUser => {

          // Create a user in your own accessible Firebase Database too
          db.doCreateUser(authUser.user.uid, username, email, gender, coin, followers, followings)
            .then(() => {
              this.setState(() => ({ ...INITIAL_STATE }));
              history.push("/");
            })
            .catch(error => {
              this.setState(updateByPropertyName('error', error));
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.setState(updateByPropertyName('error', error));
        });
      //To prevent reloading of page after submit
      event.preventDefault();
      <Redirect to="/"/>;
    }
```

I'm trying to create user with email and password using firebase authentication. Also, i am adding all the info from the input to firebase realtime database. I've searching for an answer and all came out as nothing. Anyone know how to fix??

Comment: what version of firebase js sdk are you using, and have you make sure you included auth related js?

Comment: Yes, I did. I think there is some complication here because there is firebase-admin at server.js. This is all I can come out with.

Answer (score 0):

Did you import firebase correctly?

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

Comment: import firebase from 'firebase/app'; import 'firebase/auth';   These are how I import firebase and auth.

Comment: Can you share the link to your code? is it on github?

Answer (score 0):

You have called a firebase method prior to initializing firebase `firebase.init(config);`

Answer (score 0):

Yes because you have not created an instance of the Google provider.

```
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
```

now your code will execute

```
firebase
  .auth()
    .signInWithRedirect(provider)
    .then((result) => console.log(result))
    .catch((errors) => console.log(error));
```

More Info could be found here : [firebase - link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin)